# How to output new lines read in from console

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I'm currently having an issue. I have a program that will read in a paragraph from the console (NOT a text file). The input paragraph includes new lines. I need the output to look EXACTLY like the input (I'm switch K & Y here) including those new lines in the appropriate places. The input will be something like:
TUESDAK, FEBRUARK 8

DEAR SIR,

REGARDING THE SHIPMENT ON MONDAK, IT WAS LATE AND ARRIVED ON WEDNESDAK.
(notice the skipped lines?)
I've gotten the code to work perfectly except I can't figure out how to get it to go to the next line at the correct place. Is there a way to do this in the code? Or is there a certain way I need to type in my input (I'm copy & pasting). Or am I trying to do the impossible and should just use a text file?

My code (excuse my million and 2 if/while loops):

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Y2K {
public static void main (String[]args){
    String memo = "a";
    Scanner txt = new Scanner (System.in);


    while(txt.hasNext()&& memo.length() <= 90){
         memo = txt.next();
         if (memo.equals("!")){
             System.out.println("!");
             System.exit(0);
         }
         else if (memo.contains("K") || memo.contains("Y")){
              if (memo.contains("K")){
                   memo = memo.replace("K", "Y");
              }
              else if(memo.contains("Y")){
                   memo = memo.replace("Y", "K");
              }
              System.out.print(memo + " ");
         }
         else{
             System.out.print(memo + " ");
         }
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

instead of `txt.hasNext()` and `txt.next()` use `txt.hasNextLine()` and `txt.nextLine()`. Then at the end of your while loop ad a call to  `System.out.println()` to print the new line character because you will be at the end of a line
your code should look like this (as you will now have to manually go through each char):

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Y2K {
    public static void main (String[]args){
        String memo = "";
        Scanner txt = new Scanner (System.in);


        while(txt.hasNextLine()&& memo.length() <= 90){
             memo = txt.nextLine();
             if (memo.equals("!")){
                 System.out.println("!");
                 System.exit(0);
             }
             char[] chars = memo.toCharArray()
             for(int i = 0; i<chars.length;i++){
                 if(chars[i]=='K')
                    chars[i]='Y'
                 else if(chars[i]=='Y')
                     chars[i]='K'
              }
              memo=String.valueOf(chars);
              System.out.println(memo);

         }
    }
    }
}
```